# Sencha Touch : Change value in all records in store

Tags: database, model-view-controller, synchronization, sencha-touch, store

I have a store CurrentStore where I store data entered by a user into a form. When the user presses a "Sync With Server" button, I want the data to be moved out of the CurrentStore and into a HistoryStore as well as get pushed to a server. How do I go about that??

The Store:

```
App.stores.CurrentStore = new Ext.data.Store ({
model : 'ExpenseReport',
sorters: [{
    property: 'date',
    direction: 'DESC'
}],
autoLoad : true,
autoSave : true
});
```

The Model :

```
BReimb.models.Expense = Ext.regModel('Expense', {
fields : [
    { name : 'id', type : 'integer'},
    { name : 'categ', type : 'string'},
    { name : 'cost', type : 'auto'},
    { name : 'date', type : 'date'},
    { name : 'desc', type : 'string'},
    { name : 'paymeth', type : 'string'},
    { name : 'userlogged', type : 'string'},
    { name : 'synced', type : 'string', defaultValue: 'no'}
],
proxy : {
    type : 'localstorage',
    id : 'user-reimb'
}
});
```

I have a simple button on the toolbar with an empty handler function as of now that I want to use to Sync the stores and external server database. What should I do ??

Answer (score 1):

you have to use

```
 proxy:{
    type:'ajax',
    url:' your remot server url',
     reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'results'
       }

 },
```

and your store be jsonStore